# Is the Spectrum of this ring Noetherian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[X,X^{1/2},X^{1/4},\cdots,X^{1/{2^n}},\cdots]$

Is Spec R is Noetherian a topological Space?

Here are what I know.

1.R is integral over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and hence 1 dimensional.

2.If we replace $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{C}$, the corresponding Spectrum is Noetherian since $(X-1)\subset (X^{1/2}-1)\subset (X^{1/4}-1)\subset \cdots (X^{1/{2^n}}-1)\subset \cdots$ is strictly increasing chain of radical ideals.

3.R isn't Noetherian ring.

Comment: Triple check what you wrote for typos and missing *not*s.

Comment: Cross-posted at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447235/is-the-spectrum-of-this-ring-noetherian). Please don't cross-post this quickly, and if you must cross-post, you absolutley have to link both versions together.